# Can we check Linear Independence of non-square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to create ortho normal vectors from a given set of vetors by applying Gram-Schmidt algorithm but before applying it, I am trying to check whether the vectors are linearly independent. I know in order to check linear independence we can find out the determinant of the matrix created using the given vectors. If the determinant comes out to be non-zero, it means vectors are linearly independent but what if the vectors does not make a square matrix? We cannot find the determinant of a non-square matrix. For example we have

$$
A=        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0.5 & -.7071 \\
        0 & 0.8660 & -.7071 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

So in this case (for this particular matrix)

1. Can we check linear independence?
2. Can we apply Gram-Schmidt algorithm to it?
3. Is it necessary to check linear independence before applying Gram-Schmidt algorithm?

I am not very strong in math, so trying hard to learn it.This is my first post. Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The row vectors of $A$ can be found to be independent by Gaussian elimination, the column vectors reside in $\mathbb R^2$ so at most two of them can be independent.

Comment: Can you please explain with an example?

Comment: You can apply G-S to any set of vectors. If it ever produces zero, that means that the current vector to which it’s being applied is a linear combination of the ones already processed. Discard it and move on to another one.

Comment: Are the vectors in the given matrix linearly dependent or independent and why?